# Что такое обертка класса?

Tags: c#, java

Пожалуйста, ребята, объясните что такое обертка класса, например, в Java!

Вот, например, есть значимый тип данных "int" - который 4 байта и может хранить целочисленное число. Я думал что тип "int" это просто самостоятельный тип и когда мы объявляем "интовую переменную" то компилятор просто видит ключевое слово int и понимает что необходимо выделить 4 байта памяти в стеке и положить туда значение.

Но у него есть класс обертка Integer - это как? Класс который описывает как должна работать "интовая переменная"? То есть компилятор всегда обращается к этому классу если я объявляю "интовую переменную"?

Comment: В C#, кстати, нету явных обёрток. Иногда бывает неявный boxing, но вам в подавляющем большинстве случаев не нужно об этом думать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> То есть компилятор всегда обращается к этому классу если я объявляю "интовую переменную"

Нет, интовая переменная это просто интовая переменная.

Классы `Integer`, `Long`, `Double` и им подобные обертки для примитивных типов нужны, главным образом, для использования в коллекциях, т.к. коллекции в Java могут работать только со ссылочными типами данных (наследниками класса `Object`). Т.е. вы не можете объявить, например, список `List<int>`, поэтому объявляете его с использованием обертки: `List<Integer>`.

Кроме того, эти классы-обертки содержат ряд вспомогательных методов для работы с соответствующими примитивными типами.

**Обновление**

Да, и обратите внимание на разницу между строками:

```
Integer a = 5;
Integer b = 5;
Integer c = new Integer(5);
```

В первых двух случаях значение упаковывается (*boxing*) в обертку неявно. В результате Java инициализирует переменные `a` и `b` не через `new`, а через `Integer.valueOf()`. В результате значения кешируются (только для определенного часто используемого диапазона чисел), что сэкономит нам память:

```
System.out.println(a == b);  // 'true'
```

При ручной упаковке вы гарантированно создаете новый экземпляр:

```
System.out.println(a == с);  // 'false'
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ! То есть если я напишу вот так :

Integer myint = new Integer(5);

Число "5" я уже буду хранить в куче ?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Супер ! Большое спасибо ...